# Automatic mapping of walk animations based on object velocity

Tags: scripting, animation, armature, bones, nla-editor

I'm looking for a way to automate walk cycles, so they can be reused in any scene on top of the normal armature action. NLA strips make this possible to a basic level: You can have a separate action looped over the object's armature action. However, this simply repeats the extra action at a fixed speed.

What I'm aiming for is having the walk action automatically adjusted based on the armature object's speed. You specify the velocity at which the armature action should play at normal speed, as well as how much to offset as velocity distances from that value. If the object is moving slower or faster than that, the action also loops slower or faster, making sure the feet never slide on the ground.

Additionally, speed ranges in which to activate the action would be excellent. Such could be used to have no effect when the character is standing, a walk animation as the character is walking slowly, but if the character starts moving too fast the walk animation is replaced by a run animation. Walk and run actions would each have different velocities at which they start blending in and replacing each other. If directional, different armature actions can be automated based on the character moving forward, backward, or strafing.

A further step is being able to also assign actions to acceleration / deceleration ranges. Such can be used to automate the character bending forward if it comes to a sudden stop while running.

Overall, this would allow moving a character anywhere anytime, without having to adjust the walk cycles. You simply key the object's position (or use a path) and the actions representing movement automatically loop when and how they should. Such would take a ton of work off the animator's shoulders.

I asked in other places and got no good news, so I thought to try here as well. If it's not possible yet, I hope a developer sees this and considers adding the feature or creating an addon. Thank you.

Comment: The scripting required would be so extensive, making this question more like a feature request :)

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it is a feature request and not an actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Part of it was intended as a question, although I knew the chances of this being possible are very low. I guess the only valid question is "where can I find an addon that does it", but the chances of one existing don't seem too big either.